# Firebase admin from an endpoint in Java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-endpoints, firebase-admin

I'm trying to access firebase realtime db via admin SDK from an endpoint in Java. Authentication seems to be successful, but query has no effect. No error occurs and listeners are not called. Firebase rule is set writable(assured with simulator).

Firebase db:

```
    mydbid
      +---users
           +---user0
                +---email:default@gmail.com
```

Endpoint def:

```
    @Api(
    name = "firebaseTestEndpoint",
    version = "v1",
    description = "Firebase admin test endpoint.")

public class FirebaseTestService {
    private static final Logger log = 
    Logger.getLogger(FirebaseTestService.class.getName());
    static {
        log.setLevel(Level.INFO);
    }

@ApiMethod(httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void connectToFirebase(@Named("id") String id,
                              ServletContext servletContext) {

    Map<String, Object> authVars = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    authVars.put("uid", "admin");

    try {
        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://mydbid.firebaseio.com")            
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(
                    servletContext.getResourceAsStream(
                        "/WEB-INF/firebase-credentials.json")))
                .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(authVars)
                .build();
        FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        DatabaseReference ref = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/user0/email");
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener =
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
                log.info(arg0.getRef().getPath().toString() + 
                         " changed to " + arg0.getValue(String.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                log.info("cancelled");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@ApiMethod(httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void updateEmail(@Named("id") String id) {

    Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    values.put("email", "updated@gmail.com");
    try {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/users/user0")
        .updateChildren(values, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, 
                                   DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                if (databaseError != null) {
                    throw databaseError.toException();
                }
                log.info("update completed.");
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

appengine-web.xml(related parts):

```
<basic-scaling>
  <max-instances>2</max-instances>
</basic-scaling>
```

web.xml(related parts; a space inserted before *):

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>services</param-name>
    <param-value>mypackage.FirebaseTestService</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/api/ *</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>services</param-name>
    <param-value>mypackage.FirebaseTestService</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/ *</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Tested in APIs Explorer , connectToFirebase() call is followed by a request to _ah/background, but updateEmail() does not.
 What's wrong?

Comment: Database listeners run on separate background threads. Your request threads will return before the listeners get executed. Can you try waiting for them, and see if that makes any difference? You can use the Tasks API for waiting: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/Tasks

Comment: With Tasks.await(task), DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error is returned. It seems that background thread cannot complete its job...

Comment: Can you confirm your Firebase SDK version? And also can use the ThreadManager API to ensure that your instance indeed has background thread support. You can create and start a background thread yourself to verify this: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime#background_threads_1

Comment: And also please try your code with the following line removed: authVars.put("uid", "admin"). This will help us rule out the case of a weird timeout caused by Firebase DB rules.

Comment: Firebase Admin's version is 4.1.7. Removing .setDatabaseAuthVariableOverride(authVars) has no effect.ThreadManager#createBackgroundThread(Runnable) works well.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use firebase listeners on AppEngine change basic scaling to manual scaling.

```
<manual-scaling>
   <instances>1</instances>
</manual-scaling>
```

If you want to use basic or autoscaling of AppEngine instances change firebase listeners to REST calls.

Comment: Thanks, but no effect.